# How to run this cron job on Amazon Elastic beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

My Elastic Beanstalk App has 2 environments in it:

1. Web server with RDS - for website hosting and data.
2. Worker (no RDS) - for running cron jobs

Now I have a cron job that needs to read about 1 million+ rows from the RDS table and then do something based on the `status` column of each row and then *update* each row with the result of the processing.

My problem is RDS (created in Web server env) is not accessible in the Worker env (where the cron script resides).

So how do I do this then?

Comment: Pure network configuration issue. Check subnets, security groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "RDS (created in Web server env) is not accessible in the Worker env
>   (where the cron script resides)"

Why not? If that's the case it's only because the security groups in place are preventing it. Just add a rule to the RDS security group to allow your worker environment server to connect.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, but the RDS_* env variables are not present in my Worker environment?

Comment: So add a new environment variable to the worker tier and copy/paste the value from the web tier. Unless you are constantly rebuilding or creating new environments that value shouldn't be changing. There is no real "connection" between RDS and your web tier, just a little management that Elastic Beanstalk is performing for you. You can perform that same stuff by yourself.

Comment: In that case, do you think it is better to create RDS separately and copy-paste values in both web and worker env? Are there any disadvantage of doing this?

Comment: Yes I think it is much better to create the RDS environment separately. I wouldn't want to worry about EB making changes to my database when I deploy updates to my website.